# How can I see that my suggested edit is still awaiting peer review?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I suggested an edit to an answer of a question. It said my edit needs peer review and that the edit is only visible to me.

But, when I visit the page again, my edit is gone and it looks like the site has forgotten about my edit. Now how can I get some confirmation that my edit is still in the peer review queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774707/user42723?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

And then click on the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2591912)

It is out of review, your suggested edit was rejected as an invalid edit. People do not generally take well to changing code in a post. Editing is more for fixing spelling, grammar, formatting, tag corrections, useless sentences removal, etc.

Comment: I was talking about the edit I suggested at math.stackexchange.com. But this answers my question.